# How to display seconds in year, day format in swift

Tags: swift, time, days, seconds

All i need to do is to change the way that xcode displaying my values in. My code currently displaying the age of something in minutes e.g 4503mint . I want to be able to display these values in the following format 3 days 3 hours 3 mint rather than 4503 mint. Really appreciate your help. Regards

Comment: Please explain your requirement more detailed. Maybe you can give an example what you are trying to achieve. Also - is it important if the calculated year is a leap year or not?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Sorry if I was not clear enough. But bear with me as iam new her. All i need to do is to change the way that xcode displaying my values in. My code currently displaying the age of something  in minutes e.g 4503mint . I want to be able to display these values in the following format
3 days 3 hours 3 mint rather than 4503 mint. 
Really appreciate your help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> My code currently displaying the age of something in minutes e.g 4503mint . I want to be able to display these values in the following format 3 days 3 hours 3 mint rather than 4503 mint.

You can format this using `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. Just multiply the number of minutes by 60 to get the `NSTimeInterval`, and then you can supply that to the formatter:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Full

let minutes = 4503
let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(minutes * 60)
print(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(timeInterval))
```

That will produce "3 days, 3 hours, 3 minutes" (or in whatever format appropriate for the locale for that device).

See [NSDateComponentsFormatter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously calculate it yourself (i.e. days = seconds/(3600*24)etc.), you can also look at `NSDateComponentsFormatter`, which may be exactly the functionality you are looking for with almost no coding effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate it yourself or do something like this:

```
let mySeconds = 700000
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: mySeconds) // difference to now
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy.MM.dd", options: 0, locale:     NSLocale.currentLocale())
dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```