# Converting second to date in Swift

Tags: swift, date, integer

Hello I am trying to make a count down. I want to convert an integer from second to date and show in a label with this below formats. Lets say that 2.500.000 it prints out to label 29 days 22 hour

**29 days 22 hour remained**

**15 hour 30 minutes remained**

**15 minutes remained**

Comment: Check this: [Formatting time string based on number of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39789194/1187415) or this: [How to display seconds in year, day format in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31818308/1187415).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a `DateComponentsFormatter` . That lets you generate strings that describe *amounts of time* rather than dates.

You could use the function `func string(from ti: TimeInterval) -> String?` which takes a time interval and converts it to a string describing an amount of time.

The following code, loosely based on the example code in Apple's documentation on DateComponentsFormatter:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true
formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = true
formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]


print(formatter.string(from: 123456.7) ?? "nil")
```

Generates the string `About 1 day, 10 hours, 17 minutes, 36 seconds remaining` (At least with a US English locale.)